# Using "I hurt my hands" when they feel hot

Tags: usage

I cooked noodles and put them in a bowl. I accidentally touched the bowl with my hands.

> I hurt my hands.

My hands are not injured and just feel really hot. Can *hurt* be used in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hurt" is generic.  There are many words used to specify a particular *kind* of injury, which you should try to use as appropriate:

> I touched the hot stove and *burned* my hand.
>
> I got out of bed and *bruised* my knee on the table
>
> I lifted the box and *strained* my back.
>
> I tripped and *twisted* my ankle.
>
> I *cut* my finger while slicing tomatoes.

etc.

"Burn" can be used even for mild injuries like the one you describe.  You'd just want to add some qualifier to indicate the burn is not serious.

> I burned my hand on the hot bowl, but it's fine now.

Answer (score 2):

"Hurt" can be used for anything that causes physical or emotional pain. Whether or not it is visible or caused a lasting injury is not relevant.

Having said that, if your hands are just "hot" and not in any pain, using "hurt" would not convey your intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, I would say:

> I **tried to burn** my hands. (This is being facetious but you get the idea.)

or

> I **almost burned** my hands.

It might have happened, but as you said it didn't that time. Nor did you hurt them (some pain/discomfort would not be considered *hurt*).